# How to convert Objective-c call back block to C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

Hi I want to convert this piece of objective-c code to C#

```
[yourSDKPointer.agentHandler registerWithURL:<#The registration URL#> 
                                andReference:<#The reference to be used when sending notification#>
                                onSignIn:^(LSMARegistrationStatus_t statusCode, RegistrationError_t status){
if (statusCode == LSMARegistrationStatus_registered) {
NSLog(@"Registration successful!");
}
}]
```

I am having a hard time converting this block into C#. Could you please guide me how can I convert it into C#. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the original link so we can take a look!?

Comment: If you could update your original post with the signature of this method: `registerWithURL` or at least with the types used for the parameters: **<#The registration URL#>** and **<#The reference to be used when sending notification#>**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237274/binding-a-method-for-block-in-xamarin ?